# Groovy (possibly Grails) escaping command-line parameters incorrectly

Tags: grails

**Please note:** Even though this question involves Grails, I am almost 100% sure this is a pure Groovy issue.

I have a Grails app (Grails 2.4.5, Groovy 2.4.3) that accepts a few system properties at runtime from the command-line:

```
grails -Dfoo=2 -DfizzPassword="8cv$5)iEIm8K" run-app --stacktrace
```

In my code, I then read those sys props in as String values:

```
String foo = System.getProperty('foo')
String fizzPassword = System.getProperty('fizzPassword')
```

However, because the "*fizzPassword*" property has "`$5`" in it, Groovy is somehow escaping it:

```
void doSomething() {
    String foo = System.getProperty('foo')
    String password = System.getProperty('fizzPassword')

    // Prints: "Password read was: 8cv)iEIm8K."
    //
    // When it should be printing: "Password read was 8cv$5)iEIm8K."
    println "Password read was: ${password}."
}
```

Any ideas as to how I can pass the `fizzPassword` sys prop into the app, and then read it out as a String, *without* Groovy escaping/ignoring the "`$5`" (and possibly other similar things)? In short: How does one get Groovy to read sys props verbatim off the command-line?

Comment: this is most likely your shell.  try `-DfizzPassword='8cv$5)iEIm8K'` (single quotes). please also add the actual output to the question.

Comment: Thanks @cfrick (+1) - that worked! If you can explain why in a quick answer, I'll happily give you the green check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem there has nothing to do with groovy or grails.  `$...` will be replaced from your shell:

```
$ echo "8cv$5)iEIm8K"
8cv)iEIm8K
```

You have to quote vars with sensitive chars properly.  e.g. `-DfizzPassword='8cv$5)iEIm8K'`(note the single quotes)